# Cannot add any subview to scrollView

Tags: ios, arrays, uikit

I am so confused. I cannot get any subviews to appear in a scrollView

Specifically, I want to add the view of another view controller, but I can't even add any labels or anything. I cannot see any subviews in the view debugger hierarchy either

What am I doing wrong??

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    var scrollView: UIScrollView {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .orange
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 3.0, height:  UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        return scrollView
    }

    var leftViewController: UIViewController {
        let vC = UIViewController()
        vC.view.backgroundColor = .purple
        return vC
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        leftViewController.view.frame = .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        addChild(leftViewController)
        scrollView.addSubview(leftViewController.view)
        leftViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

can achieve what I want to like this with auto layout, still hard coding widths though.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(scrollViewContainer)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(redView)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(blueView)
        scrollViewContainer.addArrangedSubview(greenView)

        scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

        scrollViewContainer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollViewContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return scrollView
    }()

    let scrollViewContainer: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()
        view.axis = .horizontal
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    let redView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    let blueView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    let greenView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width).isActive = true
        view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height).isActive = true
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }()
}
```

Comment: Can you specify why do you need a view from another view controller instead of the current view?

Comment: something like 3 view controllers will be nested in the scroll view, a very simple snapchat Esque UI. so paging enabled with 3 views that are provided by different view controllers

Comment: @RubaiyatJahanMumu - He is clearly intending to eventually add three of these child view controllers. This is a very good practice, called “view controller containment”, intended to avoid bloating of the container view controller.

Comment: What is more problematic is the reference to `UIScreen.main.bounds`. It’s not prudent to assume that an app will always take up the main screen. The OP should be referencing the `view` of this container view controller, or, better, use constraints and get out of the business of manually setting frames at all.

Comment: yeah! I am able to achieve what I want with constraints... I will add that edit. I just want to know wtf is wrong with above code so I can understand more

Comment: The problem is the computed properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nothing else, if your first example that was provided in your original question, you are using computed properties. These will return a new instance every time you reference them. You should make these stored properties:

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.backgroundColor = .orange
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 3.0, height:  UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
    return scrollView
}()

var leftViewController: UIViewController = {
    let vC = UIViewController()
    vC.view.backgroundColor = .purple
    return vC
}()
```

Note the `=` and adding the `()` at the end to designate that they’re initialized with closures.

The problem with computed properties is that because each reference returns a new instance, the child view controller’s view whose `frame` you adjusted is the not the same one you added as a subview. And the scroll view to which you added the child is not the same scroll view that you added to your container view controller.

---

In your revised question, you shared code using constraints. If you use constraints, make sure that you set [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco) to `false` for all the relevant views. Otherwise it will automatically translate the auto resizing mask of the view into constraints that will conflict with the new constraints that you are adding manually.

And you should also avoid `constraint(equalToConstant:)`, using `constraint(equalTo:)`, referencing the main view, wherever possible. For example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let view = UIScrollView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.isPagingEnabled = true
        return view
    }()

    let redView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    let greenView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(redView)
        scrollView.addSubview(greenView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // set the scroll view to be the size of the main view

            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

            // set the subviews to be the size of the main view, too

            redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),

            greenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            greenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),

            // now dictate where these subviews are in the scroll view vertically ...

            redView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),

            redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),

            // ... and horizontally

            redView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.trailingAnchor),
            greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

Frankly, since you’re talking about full-screen child view controllers, I’d jettison this code entirely, and just use `UIPageViewController` (which not only gets us out of the business of sizing child view controller’s top level views, but lets us do a more efficient “just in time” creation of child view controllers, too).

But I wanted to show what the constraints would look like if you were to do this manually.

Comment: ooooh this is a good catch. something I should keep in mind always moving forward. thanks for this tip!

Comment: one last question @rob you have been so helpful. how would you recommend getting rid of the hardcoded width constraints in my second proposed solution?

Comment: setting the constraints of each view inside of the viewDidLoad == to the size of the parent view? instead of doing the initing like I am

Comment: The hard coded frames are a problem because you’re not responding to rotation events, or other events that might change the size of the view. If you’re going to manually adjust frames, do that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` (which will catch every event that changes the size of the main view) rather than `viewDidLoad`. Using constraints gets you out of needing to do all of that yourself. With constraints, you “set and forget”, setting them once and then letting the auto layout engine take care of everything thereafter.

Comment: I had to go yesterday... I am about to sit down and read your feedback. This is extremely helpful. I am currently going through swift interviews and these are things I can mention while talking. VERY helpful.